# Splitting a least-squares problem in two, quantifying the error

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, least-squares, pseudoinverse

I have formulated a least-squares problem of the form:

$$\min_{\pmb{x}}\|\pmb{B}\pmb{A}\pmb{x} - \pmb{b}\|^2_2.$$

The resulting solution is given by (I assume $(\pmb{A}^T\pmb{B}^T\pmb{B}\pmb{A})$ is invertible):

$$\pmb{x}^* = (\pmb{A}^T\pmb{B}^T\pmb{B}\pmb{A})^{-1}\pmb{A}^T\pmb{B}^T\pmb{b}.$$

The matrix $(\pmb{A}^T\pmb{B}^T\pmb{B}\pmb{A})$ has turned out to be fairly ill-conditioned in my case, however, so I have decided to split the problem into two parts for efficiency reason (I am using an iterative solver):

$$\min_{\pmb{y}}\|\pmb{\pmb{B}y-\pmb{b}}\|^2_2 \implies \pmb{y}^* = (\pmb{B}^T\pmb{B})^{-1}\pmb{B}^T\pmb{b},$$
$$\min_{\pmb{z}}\|\pmb{A}\pmb{z}-\pmb{y}^*\|^2_2 \implies \pmb{z}^* = (\pmb{A}^T\pmb{A})^{-1}\pmb{A}^T\pmb{y}^*,$$

where I have assumed that $(\pmb{B}^T\pmb{B})$ and $(\pmb{A}^T\pmb{A})$ are invertible. I interpret those two steps as two subsequent $l_2$ projections (i.e. $\pmb{b}$ is projected through $\pmb{B}$ into $\pmb{B}\pmb{y}^*$, and then $\pmb{y}^*$ is projected through $\pmb{A}$ into $\pmb{A}\pmb{z}^*$).

Is there a way to analytically asses the quality of:

$$\pmb{z}^* = (\pmb{A}^T\pmb{A})^{-1}\pmb{A}^T(\pmb{B}^T\pmb{B})^{-1}\pmb{B}^T\pmb{b}$$

when compared to:

$$\pmb{x}^* = (\pmb{A}^T\pmb{B}^T\pmb{B}\pmb{A})^{-1}\pmb{A}^T\pmb{B}^T\pmb{b}?$$

I intuitively understand that the closer $\pmb{B}^T\pmb{B}$ is to the identity matrix, the closer those results are. However I would like something more concrete.

Comment: Writing the solution in terms of the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse will obviate the issues with conditioning, i.e. $\;x^* = (BA)^+b\quad$

Comment: @greg I am using an iterative solver because the matrices are very large and very sparse. I cannot even store the inverse in memory, so this is not an option.

Comment: You're suggesting substituting $(A^+B^+)$ for $(BA)^+.\;$ This is not generally valid, the correct formula is 
$$(BA)^+ = \big(B^+BA\big)^+\,\big(BAA^+\big)^+$$
The quality of your solution depends on the closeness of the two matrices $$\delta_{AB}=\big\|A^+B^+-(BA)^+\big\|^2_F$$
or perhaps the closeness of the individual factors
$$\delta_{A}=\big\|A^+-(B^+BA)^+\big\|^2_F\qquad
\delta_{B}=\big\|B^+-(BAA^+)^+\big\|^2_F$$ If you construct a problem with smaller dimensions but similar characteristics, you might be able to estimate these quantites, then extrapolate to the larger system.

Comment: @greg Do you have a paper I could refer to for the formula $(BA)^{+} = (B^{+}BA)^{+}(BAA^{+})^{+}$? In my case $(B^{+}B) = I$, so I get $(BA)^{+} = A^{+}(BAA^{+})^{+}$ from this formula, which means that $\delta_A = 0$, although I don't think I can guarantee that $\delta_B$ is zero. Thank you very much for these. Feel free to add your comment as an actual answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Two other predictors of the error seem to be: $\|\pmb{B}^T\pmb{B}-\pmb{I}\|^2_F$ and $\|\pmb{A}\pmb{A}^{+}-\pmb{I}\|^2_F$. Also I could try initialising with an initial guess $\pmb{z}^*$ in my iterative solver, and solve the original system, it could be that the guess is good enough to make up for the condition number.